# Generate all possible choices of elements each from a distinct set

Tags: c++, algorithm, set, cartesian-product

Suppose that we have `k` sets each of which contains `q` elements. I want to generate all possible sets in which we select exactly 1 element from each set. Assume that the sets are represented as a table where each row is a set and its columns are its elements. Also assume that all elements are indexed row-wise like this

Set 1: 1 2 3

Set 2: 4 5 6

Set 3: 7 8 9

The thing is that k,q may vary so I cannot use nested for loops. I work in C++ and this structure is actually a `std::vector` of `std::vector` of `int`, but I am not asking for code here, just an idea on how to do this.

Comment: *"The thing is that k,q may vary so I cannot use nested for loops."* Why?

Comment: @CinCout I might be missing something but I am not aware of any way to generate as many nested loops as you need. In my case, I would need k nested loops. Please explain.

Comment: `k` and `q` vary but are known right? In the example, you gave, you will have a total of 27 sets. I'd just have the loop run `q^k` times. What's the problem?

Comment: @CinCout My point is that you will have to change the code every time k changes, to add or remove nested loops which is not practical. Please provide some code or pseudocode to clarify your idea.

Comment: Check DAle's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Recursive**

```
using sets = vector<vector<int>>;

void rec(int index, const sets& s, vector<int>& v) {
    for (int next : s[index]) {
        v[index] = next;
        if (index + 1 == s.size()) {
            output(v);
        } else {
            rec(index+1, s, v);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    sets s = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    int q = s[0].size();
    vector<int> v(q);
    rec(0, s, v);
    return 0;
}
```

**Non recursive**

The main idea is that every choice can be encoded by a number in base-`q` numeral system. And all you need to do is to iterate through all base-`q` numbers with `length <= n`. Every digit of the number is an index in the corresponding set.

For example, we have 2 sets with 3 numbers. You need to iterate through `{00, 01, 02, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22}`.

```
using sets = vector<vector<int>>;

void non_rec(const sets& s) {
    int q = s[0].size();
    int k = s.size();
    vector<int> v(q);
    int cnt = (int)pow(q, k);

    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
        int tmp = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
            v[j] = s[j][tmp % q];
            tmp /= q;
        }
        output(v);
    }
}

int main() {
    sets s = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    non_rec(s);
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/V58I7W

Comment: @GauravSehgal, On every iteration of the main loop we just get digits of `i` in q-ary numeral system and use them as indexes in corresponding sets.

Comment: This assumes pow(q,k) fits in int, which might be too small in some settings and/or platforms. Better use unsigned long for i and cnt. Also, on some embedded platforms, the "double" type returned by pow() may only have single precision. It's saver to calculate cnt in a for loop with integer multiplications.

Comment: @JoachimWagner, I agree with you, but that's just an exemplary code, not production-ready. It lacks an attention to the corner cases (it doesn't work with an empty set, for example), possible overflows, good names for the variables. But on the other hand, it's not filled with excessive details that would complicate the code

Answer (score 1):

A hard coded solution would be

```
for (int a1 : v[0]) {
  for (int a2 : v[1]) {
    for (int a3 : v[2]) {
      for (int a4 : v[3]) {
        for (int a5 : v[4]) {
            do_job(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To make it generic, you may do:

```
bool increase(const std::vector<std::set<int>>& v,
              std::vector<std::set<int>::iterator>& it)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0, size = it.size(); i != size; ++i) {
        const std::size_t index = size - 1 - i;
        ++it[index];
        if (it[index] == v[index].end()) {
            it[index] = v[index].begin();
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

template <typename F>
void iterate(const std::vector<std::set<int>>& v, F&& do_job)
{
    std::vector<std::set<int>::iterator> its;
    its.reserve(v.size());
    for (auto& s : v) {
        its.push_back(s.begin());
    }

    do {
        do_job(its);
    } while (increase(v, its));
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/J5IeKE)

Answer (score 0):

This does the job?

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
for(auto& r : v)
    for(auto i : r)
        // use i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unaware of the number of sets and of the number of elements in each set, then you can generate the set of all elements you want the following way.  Basically, you can loop over all the elements of a set and include that in the previous remaining product of whatever had been computed so far.  Let me know if something is still unclear

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void append_results(const std::set<int>& set,
                    std::vector<std::vector<int>>& results);

int main() {

    auto sets = std::vector<std::set<int>>{
        std::set<int>{1, 2, 3},
        std::set<int>{4, 5, 6},
        std::set<int>{7, 8, 9}
    };

    auto results = std::vector<std::vector<int>>{};

    for (const auto& set : sets) {
        append_results(set, results);
    }

    for (const auto& result : results) {
        for (auto integer : result) {
            cout << integer << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void append_results(const std::set<int>& set,
                    std::vector<std::vector<int>>& results) {

    if (results.empty()) {
        for (auto integer : set) {
            results.push_back(std::vector<int>{integer});
        }
    } else {
        auto old_results = results;
        results.clear();
        for (auto integer : set) {
            for (auto old_result : old_results) {
                old_result.push_back(integer);
                results.push_back(std::move(old_result));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use backtracking here to generate all subsets

```
  void func(vector<vector<int> > arr,int row,vector<int> &temp,vector<vector<int> > &ans)
  {
    if(row>=arr.size())
    {
        ans.push_back(temp);    //You have generated one of the answers.store it
        return;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<arr[row].size();i++)
    {
        temp.push_back(arr[row][i]);  //Pick an element from current set
        func(arr,row+1,temp,ans);     //recurse for next set
        temp.pop_back();              //Remove from current set to include next element from this set(for loop)
    }
  }
```

Working code: http://ideone.com/RvHMNT